# How to find the distance of two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have two lists as the following:

```
ab = {1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1};
ac = {1, -1, -1,  1, 1, 1};
```

How I can find the difference (more precisely, the **edit distance**) between them? In this case the result should be 1, since there is one item difference between `ab` and `ac`.

Note: in my case, the list elements only take the values `1` and `-1`, and both lists are one-dimensional of the same length, but it is always nice to see more general solutions (elements are of `Reals`, lists are matrices, etc.).

Thank you.

Comment: Will you always deal in integers only?

Comment: ... or even only 1 and -1?

Comment: values are only 1 and -1

Comment: Then you are in for a treat (see answers)! Please edit your question to include the 1/-1 information.

Answer (score 22):

There is an appropriate metrics:

```
HammingDistance[ab, ac]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

one could use also (but in general it yields different results since it counts transpositions, deletions etc.)

```
DamerauLevenshteinDistance[ab, ac]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Comment: Strangely `HammingDistance` doesn't work for mixed data i.e having both Integer and Symbols.

Comment: @Blackbird What problems have you encountered? How many should it be `HammingDistance[{3, 2, a, 10, b, 5, 11, c}, {3, 2, a, 11, b, Pi, 11, 3}]` ?  `3`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I am sorry for reading the definition in wrong way.My bad, you are correct.

Comment: @Blackbird Note that `HammingDistance` works also for strings (there is useful the `IgnoreCase` option) unlike the other methods.

Answer (score 16):

For Integer data we also could write:

```
 Tr @ Unitize @ BitXor[ab, ac]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

For Real data we can use the slightly slower but also shorter:

```
Tr @ Unitize[ab - ac]
```

---

Blackbird challenged me to provide a method that works on all input types.  My approach is to select between methods depending on data.

```
diff[a__?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] := Tr @ Unitize @ BitXor @ a
diff[a__?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Tr @ Unitize @ Subtract @ a
diff[a_, b_] := HammingDistance[a, b]
```

---

Timings for some of the methods posted so far (search the site for `timeAvg`):

```
{ab, ac} = List @@ RandomInteger[2, {2, 250000}];  (* List @@ to prevent unpacking *)

HammingDistance[ab, ac]                  // timeAvg
Count[MapThread[Equal, {ab, ac}], False] // timeAvg
Tr @ Unitize @ BitXor[ab, ac]            // timeAvg
diff[ab, ac]                             // timeAvg
```

> 0.009984
>
> 0.05428
>
> 0.0005488
>
> 0.0005744

Now with Real data:

```
{ab, ac} = N /@ {ab, ac};

HammingDistance[ab, ac]                  // timeAvg
Count[MapThread[Equal, {ab, ac}], False] // timeAvg
Tr @ Unitize[ab - ac]                    // timeAvg
diff[ab, ac]                             // timeAvg
```

> 0.01872
>
> 0.0748
>
> 0.00312
>
> 0.0021728

(I learned something from this test: `Subtract[a,b]` is faster than `a-b` on packed reals.)

Now something unpackable:

```
{ab, ac} = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], {2, 250000}];

HammingDistance[ab, ac]                  // timeAvg
Count[MapThread[Equal, {ab, ac}], False] // timeAvg
diff[ab, ac]                             // timeAvg
```

> 0.005488
>
> 0.0524
>
> 0.005496

Comment: I *knew* this was one of those explode-in-your-face threads ;P

Comment: @Yves Please define that.

Comment: Simple/trivial question, one gazillion possible (and sometimes surprising and/or creative) answers. Oh, and my timings are usually abysmal...

Comment: @Yves Ah, one of *those*.

Comment: Is the term unsuitable / lost in translation?

Comment: @Yves no, I'm just [thick](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thickheaded).

Comment: Anyway, now you´ll have to do the honors and get timings for all solutions to come.

Comment: This bitwise operation is ultrafast but it doesn't work for Symbol based list, this will really limit its use. I know OP has not asked this, but I was just thinking about variations.

Comment: @Blackbird It would be quite simple to write a master function to select between these methods depending on the data.  I sought to provide the best solutions for specific cases.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : I doubt it wil be this fast, its lightening fast.

Comment: @Blackbird Are you saying you feel the overhead of the selector will be too great?  I think it would be reasonable to only trigger the optimized method for packed arrays, and pass anything else to `HammingDistance`, and I would expect that approach to be fast.  I guess I should implement it as proof, or counter-proof.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : ya it will be good post to learn from, please post your idea.

Comment: @Blackbird Added.  I hope you will agree that overhead is insignificant.

Comment: @yves "blow up in your face" is a tad more idiomatic... :)

Comment: @cormullion ahhh... thanks for scratching that idiosyncratic itch :-)

Answer (score 9):

You could do this

```
ab = {1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1};
ac = {1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1};

EditDistance[ab, ac]
```

which would give a result even if the lists had different lengths (or whatever).

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EditDistance.html) says:

> EditDistance[*u*, *v*] gives the number of one-element deletions, insertions, and substitutions required to transform *u* to *v*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to down-vote this.  `EditDistance` is not the same thing.  Incidentally it is a far more complex measure and will be unusably slow on long vectors.

Comment: The OP said “How I can find the difference between them? Now in our case the result should be 1, since there is one item difference between ab and ac.”, which is such a loose definition of “difference” that `EditDistance` is a feasible candidate. Though I agree with your comment about complexity.

Comment: Okay, I have to admit you're right.  My impression of the question didn't allow for that but I was wrong.  I removed my down-vote (I had to edit to do this).

Answer (score 8):

A *very* basic approach:

```
Count[Equal @@@ Thread[{ab, ac}], False]
```

> `1`

or perhaps:

```
Count[MapThread[Equal, {ab, ac}], False]
```

> `1`

*Now* if there is only 1 and -1 to watch out for, this will also do (thanks to Aky for pointing out a glaring error):

```
Plus @@ Abs[ab - ac]/2
```

Comment: You don't need `Thread` in the last one: `Tr[ab-ac]/-2`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard just came to my senses (usually I do not use `Thread` that much anyway), and `Tr` would most likely even be faster - benchmark away!

Comment: It is too short for the answer so maybe you can add `Count[ab ac, -1]` somewhere for 1/-1 data case.

Comment: @Kuba good one! You sure you do not want to answer yourself?

Comment: @Kuba Short is the best kind of answer.  I encourage you to post it. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I´d like to see `Tr[ab - ac]/-2` beaten in terms of brevity, but it is lovely, so please add it to your answer.

Comment: @YvesKlett Oh crikey, I'm losing my marbles faster than I feared.  I didn't remember writing that! :-S

Comment: @Mr.Wizard *now* you see what I meant by "explode in your face" :-)

Comment: @Yves Literally LOL.  I just wish it wasn't over my own early senility.

Comment: Its all weather snippet. Any type of data in list.

Answer (score 7):

These results are specific to the case where the data are 1|-1, and may be specific to v6.

```
<<Developer`
n = 10^7
PackedArrayQ[ a = RandomInteger[1,n]*2 - 1 ]
PackedArrayQ[ b = RandomInteger[1,n]*2 - 1 ]
(* 10000000
   True
   True *)

AbsoluteTiming[ (Length@a - a.b)/2  ]
(* {0.435134, 4998582} *)

AbsoluteTiming[ Tr@Unitize@Subtract[a,b] ]
(* {0.792662, 4998582} *)

AbsoluteTiming[ Tr@Unitize@BitXor[a,b] ]
(* {0.883002, 4998582} *)

aa = FromPackedArray@a;
bb = FromPackedArray@b;

AbsoluteTiming[ (Length@aa - aa.bb)/2  ]
(* {1.373384, 4998582} *)

AbsoluteTiming[ Tr@Unitize@Subtract[aa,bb] ]
(* {1.366143, 4998582} *)

AbsoluteTiming[ Tr@Unitize@BitXor[aa,bb] ]
(* {2.590419, 4998582} *)
```

Comment: I get the same rankings in v7.  I hadn't realized that `Subtract` was faster than `BitXor`.

Comment: Ah, I see now that it's only faster on this data, not general Integer data.  Nevertheless +1 well earned for teaching me something.

Answer (score 6):

I will abuse the fact that OP hasn't said if it is more general question.

This is my solution fo `1/-1` data case:

```
Count[ab ac, -1]
```

Comment: @YvesKlett Here is another fun one for -1/1:  `Tr@Log[ab ac]/I/Pi`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If we a priori know the `Length` then this one is shorter: `(n - ab.ac)/2`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you could save one character with `Tr@Log[-1, ab ac]`