# Counting the number of instances where items at the same position in two matrices are equal?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given two matrices having the same dimensions:

```
m1 = {{1, a, 2}, {4, 5, 0}, {g, a, d}}
m2 = {{1, b, 2}, {7, 2, 0}, {a, a, a}}
```

Is there a built-in function that can return a count `count` for the number of instances where two entries in the same matrix position are equal?  In the above example, for instance, we would have `count =  4`.

Note that, because I need to have a mix of numerical and string values in each matrix, I can't simply subtract the two matrices and look for non-zero positions.  I'd also like to have `0` valued items in either matrix.

Comment: Byt why not `m1 - m2 // N // Count[#, 0., {2}] &`

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31771/5478)

Comment: The built-in function you are looking for is [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Count.html). Apply it like so: `Count[m1 - m2, 0 | 0., {2}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this as simple as you're hoping, but:

```
Count[MapThread[SameQ, {m1, m2}, 2], True, 2]
```

would work.

Answer (score 4):

```
"a" - "a"
```

> 0

Therefore

```
Count[Flatten[m1 - m2], 0]
```

> 4

**Update** thanks to comments

```
m1 = {{-1., a, 2}, {4, 5, 0}, {g, a, d}};
m2 = {{-1., b, 2}, {7, 2, 0}, {a, a, a}};

Count[Flatten[m1 - m2], 0 | 0.]
```

> 4

Comment: But `1. - 1. == 0.`

Comment: `Count[m1 - m2, 0 | 0., {2}]` (variant of Kuba comment made to the question) might be an improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Following [How to find the distance of two lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31771/how-to-find-the-distance-of-two-lists/31775#31775) if your arrays are numeric this is much faster:

```
count[m1_, m2_] := Times @@ Dimensions[m1] - Total[Unitize @ Subtract[m1, m2], -1]
```

For an explanation of why [`Subtract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Subtract.html) is written out see:

- [Why are numeric division and subtraction not handled better in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121)

#### Timings:

```
{m1, m2} = List @@ RandomInteger[9, {2, 3000, 4000}];

Count[MapThread[SameQ, {m1, m2}, 2], True, 2] // Timing
Count[Flatten[m1 - m2], 0 | 0.]               // Timing
count[m1, m2]                                 // Timing
```

> ```
> {3.198021, 1199603}
>
> {1.248008, 1199603}
>
> {0.046800, 1199603}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
{a, b} = Dimensions[m1];

Count[Table[m1[[i, j]] === m2[[i, j]], {i, a}, {j, b}], True, 2]
```

> 4

Comment: This is effectively the same as nikie's method but without leveraging *Mathematica*'s array operations (i.e. `MapThread`); it is therefore several times slower. (14.1 seconds on the test in my answer.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm still fairly new to programming. Please forgive me if my answer is slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to know what elements as well as count:

```
{#, Length@#} &@(# -> Extract[m1, #] & /@ Position[N[m1 - m2], 0.])
```

gives: {{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 2, {2, 3} -> 0, {3, 2} -> a}, 4}