# Discrete Measure between Binary Vectors

Tags: boolean-computation, distance

I would like a discrete distance measure between two binary vectors (or strings).
Like `HammingDistance` but I want the vectors to be considered closer if they have more matches that are separated by zeros (or a default value).

For example: given the four vectors and distance measure `thedistancemeasure`

```
           vec1={1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1};
           vec2={1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0};

           vec3={1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0};
           vec4={0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0};
```

such that.

```
  thedistancemeasure[vec1,vec2]< thedistancemeasure[vec3,vec4]
```

> True

The measure likes small group of matches that are well separated versus a large group of matches that are "connected" or less seperated.

The amount of zeros shouldn't matter, but if it does, I prefers more zeros to give a smaller measure. The more separated the better.

If possible I also want the measure to give even closer distances for higher count of well separated correctly matched ones, for example.

```
            vec5={1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1};
            vec6={1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};
```

would give.

```
 thedistancemeasure[vec1,vec2]>thedistancemeasure[vec5,vec6]
```

> True

The size of the vectors would always be fixed.

It might be possible using the output from `ListCorrelate` since it should give the position correlations between lists.

Comment: Do you want the distance function or maybe an function for pairs of pairs is enough.

Comment: @Kuba for pairs is enough

Comment: Since `vec3` and `vec4` are identical, shouldn't they have distance?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I know right, it is a bit confusing how to accomplish this.  Maybe I misunderstood Kuba's question.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say that the two vectors have zero distance.

Comment: For your second example did you mean to use `<` where you have `>`?  If not I don't follow the description.

Comment: > < are correct. I will try rewrite to make clear that the separation of 0 is between correctly matched points.

Comment: I think, your last line of code should have `thedistancemeasure[vec5, vec6]` on the right hand side.

Comment: @kguler yep just noticed that, I think today is "I'm having a stroke day".

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now it is fixed. Sorry for that. I read it twice now, hopefully it makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[distF1, distF2]
distF1 = With[{p = Intersection @@ (Flatten@ SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"]&/@ #)}, 
         -Length @ p] &;
distF2 = With[{p = Intersection @@ (Flatten@SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"]&/@#)},
         -Total[Differences@p]] &;
```

Example:

```
vec1 = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
vec2 = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
vec3 = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
vec4 = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
vec5 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
vec6 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
vecs = {vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4, vec5, vec6};
pairs = Partition[vecs, 2];
plabels = {"v1v2", "v3v4", "v5v6"};
```

Sort pairs lexicographically in ascending order using the distance function `distF1` and breaking ties with the distance function `distF2`:

```
SortBy[pairs, {distF1, distF2}] /. Thread[pairs -> plabels]
{"v5v6", "v1v2", "v3v4"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble following your examples but perhaps you can [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) your vectors and compare length:

```
vec1 = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
vec3 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
vec5 = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};

Length /@ Split /@ {vec1, vec3, vec5}
```

> ```
> {4, 3, 5}
> ```

Combine this with `HammingDistance` or [alternatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31771/121) with whatever weighting you prefer.

Comment: I changed the example so they are not comparing two identical vectors, thanks. This looks like the way forward!