# Minimize distance between two lists

Tags: mathematical-optimization, charts

Writing:

```
expectedresults = {4, 8, 5, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 9, 3};
achievedresults = {3, 6, 4, 2, 10, 7, 2, 4, 8, 4};
p1 = BarChart[expectedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Blue]];
p2 = BarChart[achievedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Red]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

I get:

[image]

On the other hand, if I write:

```
k = 0.83;
expectedresults = {4, 8, 5, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 9, 3};
achievedresults = {3, 6, 4, 2, 10, 7, 2, 4, 8, 4} k;
p1 = BarChart[expectedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Blue]];
p2 = BarChart[achievedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Red]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

I get:

[image]

where it is clear that, compared to the previous case, in some bars the gap has decreased and in others it has increased.

Question: How can I determine the best value of `k` to get the smallest possible gap?

---

Writing:

```
h = -0.35;
k = 0.83;
expectedresults = {4, 8, 5, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 9, 3};
achievedresults = h + k {3, 6, 4, 2, 10, 7, 2, 4, 8, 4};
p1 = BarChart[expectedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Blue]];
p2 = BarChart[achievedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Red]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

I get:

[image]

Question 2: is it possible to determine the pair of values `h`, `k` that minimize the gap?

Comment: This is a related question:  [How to find the distance of two lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31771/how-to-find-the-distance-of-two-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Using two parameters:

```
lmf2 = LinearModelFit[data, t, t];
Normal@lmf2
```

> 1.76563 + 0.546875 t

```
lmf2["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {1.76563, 0.546875}

```
Fit[data, {1, t}, t]
```

> 1.76563 + 0.546875 t

```
ClearAll[h, k]
NMinimize[Total[Subtract[expectedresults, h + k achievedresults]^2], {h, k}]
```

> {43.3594, {h -> 1.76562, k -> 0.546875}}

```
N @ LeastSquares[Thread[{1, achievedresults}], expectedresults]
```

> {1.76563, 0.546875}

**Original answer:**

```
expectedresults = {4, 8, 5, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 9, 3};
achievedresults = {3, 6, 4, 2, 10, 7, 2, 4, 8, 4};
data = Transpose[{ achievedresults,expectedresults}];
```

You can use [`LinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html) or [`Fit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html) or [`NMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) or [`LeastSquares`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html) to get the value of `k` that minimizes the sum of squared distances between `expectedresults` and `k achievedresults`:

```
lmf = LinearModelFit[data, t, t, IncludeConstantBasis -> False]

Normal@lmf
```

> 0.828025 t

```
Normal @ LinearModelFit[{Transpose[{achievedresults}], expectedresults}]
```

> 0.828025 #1

```
Fit[data, {t}, t]
```

> 0.828025 t

```
ClearAll[k]
NMinimize[Total[Subtract[expectedresults, k achievedresults]^2], k]
```

> {49.7134, {k -> 0.828025}}

```
N@LeastSquares[Thread[{achievedresults}], expectedresults]
```

> {0.828025}

```
k = lmf["BestFitParameters"][[1]]
```

> 0.828025

```
p1 = BarChart[expectedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Blue]];
p2 = BarChart[k achievedresults, ChartStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Red]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[Transpose@{expectedresults, achievedresults,  k achievedresults}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
 ChartLegends -> {"expectedresults", "achievedresults", "k achievedresults"}]
```

[image]

Comment: For general data you can always find several values of $k$ that eliminate the difference between whichever bars you like.

Comment: @TeM, please see the update.

Comment: @TeM, If you compare the `NMinimize` result adding the intercept parameter improves the squared loss from `49.7134` to `43.3594`.

Answer (score 7):

```
{k, h} = PseudoInverse[{#, 1} & /@ achievedresults].expectedresults
```

> {35/64, 113/64}

Comment: Why do you add a zero column? I think `PseudoInverse[Transpose[{achievedresults}]].expectedresults` will do

Comment: @MeMyselfI Nice! Even better